# How to handle relationships with a command bus approach using DTO's

Tags: php, cqrs

In a new greenfield project I'm using a command bus approach, problem I'm encountering is how I should handle relationships.

For example, an Order has multiple OrderLines, a Shipping and Invoice address.

Since I'm using a command bus approach I want to pass a DTO to my command bus holding all the information necessary to create an Order.

Should this command also hold relationships (i.e. an CreateOrderTask, CreateOrderAddress)?

My directory/file structure looks like this:

```
- Infrastructure
-- Ui
--- Web
---- CreateOrderController.php
-- ....
- Application
-- CreateOrder
--- CreateOrder.php
--- CreateOrderHandler.php
--- CreateOrderLine.php (?)
- Domain
-- Order
--- Order.php
--- OrderLine.php
--- Address.php
-- ...
```

So should the CreateOrder class look like this:

```
// CreateOrder.php

<?php

class CreateOrder {

    /** @var CreateOrderLine[] */
    protected $createOrderLines;

    public function __construct(array $createOrderLines) 
    {
        $this->createOrderLines = $createOrderLines;
    }

    public function getCreateOrderLines()
    {
        return $this->createOrderLines;
    }
}
```

Although I think there are many correct answers, I'm looking for a best practice. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Nope. Just pass around the ID of other entities and let the "receiver" of that message rehydrate the entity from the read-model.

Comment: @kayess so I'll end up with a CreateOrder use-case, CreateOrderLine use-case, CreateAddress use-case and so on? That'll introduce sequential issues if the command is executed asynchronously (which are solvable ofcourse)

Comment: @kayess I don't think we're on the same line ;-) through my controller I'm creating a CreateOrder DTO which I pass onto the command bus, does this DTO also contain order lines etc. or should that by different commands going through the command bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your transaction boundaries.

If you need that **all the commands must succeed or fail together** then you in fact must have a *bigger* command with all the data needed.

If any of the sub-commands fails and the system is still in valid state then you don't need a bigger command and you may send multiple commands in some kind of batch, each one having its own transaction boundary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So in the case of an e-commerce system where an order is only correct if it also has products I should have an CreateOrder DTO which holds a list/array with one or multiple instances of an OrderLine DTO?

Comment: @MarcoVeenendaal Yes. In general, `Order` is populated using CRUD, for example as a shopping cart but after the cart is done filling then the behaviors are implemented using DDD. So, your first command sent to the `Order` aggregate should be `placeOrder` that checks the order validity, although you could have a lot of prior CRUD commands like `addOrderItem` or `removeOrderItem`

Answer (score 2):

eCommerce is quite popular domain and here there might be more interesting to look at what business things of the behaviour of your system.

Moving away from CQRS a little, I would ask you some "DDD-style" questions:

- Where does the order come from?
- What `CreateOrder` means? Who creates them?
- What about the shopping cart? Isn't it being populated by one line?
- Doesn't your business need to know about aborted shopping carts too?

I would warn you from over-simplifying the domain in question and over-engineer the solution...

If you at the end of the day will have a shopping cart - you probably have commands to add goods to it. These commands will be issued asynchronously. There will be no `AddShoppingCartHeader` command because it does not make any sense for the business. On checkout, the cart will probably be converted to an order. Or, after a timeout, it will discarded and a lead will be created. If this is all valid - you probably would want to look at the process manager pattern (also called Saga in many messaging frameworks).